# Uncaught reference error not defined at onchange

Tags: javascript, html

I have this program with 3 dropdown menus that should be able to change the values in a dropdown menu based on the selection made in the previous dropdown menu. But when i run it and try changing something in the dropdown menu i get this error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: populateDropdown2 is not defined
at onchange"

Does anyone know what to do?

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Dropdown Menus</title>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="dropdown1">Dropdown 1:\</label>
    <select id="dropdown1" onchange="populateDropdown2(test)">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>

    <label for="dropdown2">Dropdown 2:</label>
    <select id="dropdown2" onchange="populateDropdown3(test1)">
        <option value="">Please select an option</option\>
    </select>

    <label for="dropdown3">Dropdown 3:</label>
    <select id="dropdown3">
        <option value="">Please select an option</option>
    </select>

    <script>
        // Define the options for dropdown 2 based on the value selected in dropdown 1
        function populateDropdown2(test) {
            var dropdown1 = document.getElementById("dropdown1");
            var dropdown2 = document.getElementById("dropdown2");
            var value = dropdown1.value;
            dropdown2.innerHTML = "";

            if (value === "1") {
                var option1 = document.createElement("option");
                option1.value = "1a";
                option1.text = "Option 1a";
                dropdown2.add(option1);

                var option2 = document.createElement("option");
                option2.value = "1b";
                option2.text = "Option 1b";
                dropdown2.add(option2);
            }
            else if (value === "2") {
                var option3 = document.createElement("option");
                option3.value = "2a";
                option3.text = "Option 2a";
                dropdown2.add(option3);

                var option4 = document.createElement("option");
                option4.value = "2b";
                option4.text = "Option 2b";
                dropdown2.add(option4);
            }
            else if (value === "3") {
                var option5 = document.createElement("option");
                option5.value = "3a";
                option5.text = "Option 3a";
                dropdown2.add(option5);

                var option6 = document.createElement("option");
                option6.value = "3b";
                option6.text = "Option 3b";
                dropdown2.add(option6);
            }
        }

        // Define the options for dropdown 3 based on the value selected in dropdown 2
        function populateDropdown3() {
            var dropdown2 = document.getElementById("dropdown2");
            var dropdown3 = document.getElementById("dropdown3");
            var value = dropdown2.value;
            dropdown3.innerHTML = "";

            if (value === "1a") {
                var option1 = document.createElement("option");
                option1.value = "1a1";
                option1.text = "Option 1a1";
                dropdown3.add(option1);

                var option2 = document.createElement("option");
                option2.value = "1a2";
                option2.text = "Option 1a2";
                dropdown3.add(option2);
            }
            else if (value === "1b") {
                var option3 = document.createElement("option");
                option3.value = "1b1";
                option3.text = "Option 1b1";
                dropdown3.add(option3);

                var option4 = document.createElement("option");
                option4.value = "1b2";
                option4.text = "option 1b2";
                dropdown3.add(option3);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

i dont know what to try im js noob

Comment: can you properly format your code pls? and why is your HTML so messy?

Comment: Missing closing `</script>` tag

Comment: what is this `test` and `test1` that you sent in your onchange functions? `onchange="populateDropdown2(test)"` they are undefined and there is no point sending those if you are not gonna even use them

Comment: Thanks Konrad! Thal helped :D